# Invalid Syntax on Python Finite State Machne

Tags: python, if-statement

I am Trying to make a computer vision finite state machine for some plant stuff in my garden and my if else statement is giving me trouble. Can I get help with the proper syntax

```
# my_states.py

from state import State

# Start of our states
class ObservingState(State):
    """
    The state which indicates that there are limited device capabilities.
    """

    def on_event(self, event):
    if event == 'Needs_Nitrogen':
        return Nitrogen_Solution_pump()
    elif event == 'Needs_Potasium':
        return Potasium_Solution_Pump()
    elif event == 'Needs_phosphorus':
        return Phosphorus_Solution_Pump()
    elif event == 'Needs_Water':
        return Water_Pump_On_10_seconds()
    elif event == 'Needs_Light':
        return Light_On()
    elif event == 'Needs_Darnkess':
        return Light_Off()
    elif event == 'Needs_Less_water':
        return Release_Valve_On_10_seconds()
    elif event == 'Plants_Healthy'
        return ObservingState()

    return self
```

Comment: You want `elif` everywhere you currently have `else` - and the last one is missing the colon, too.

Comment: that still returns an error

Comment: *What* error? Moving from a syntax error to your code running but not working is at least a step forward: research the error, fix it, repeat.

Comment: File "C:\Users\adam\.spyder-py3\mystates.py", line 34
    elif: event == 'Plants_Healthy'
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's the line missing the colon that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately syntax errors are considered off topic [help]

Comment: `elif event == 'Plants_Healthy'` is missing a colon at  the end.

Comment: ever just see something 1000 times and it doesn't click....till it just does